# Extract specific element of a dict in a tuple in a list of tuple

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples that is composed of a string and a dictionary like the following

```
List = [
    ("mike", {
        'age': 27, 
        'favorite food': 'pizza', 
        'favorite drink': 'beer'
    }), 
    ("jessie", {
        'age': 35, 
        'favorite food': 'eggs',
        'favorite drink': 'tea'
    }), 
    ("frank", {
        'age': 14, 
        'favorite food': 'bread',
        'favorite drink':'fanta'
    })
]
```

I would like to loop through that list and extract the data in the [favorite drink] in order to compare it with another.

Lets say I loop through the list and check if **user** likes beer, he gets a score of 1.

so far I've gotten :

```
for x in list:
    if list[0][1] == 'beer':
         beer-counter += 1
```

The problem is I'm only accessing the dictionary, not the element of the dictionary with what I have.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i have managed to solve my problem by combining all your answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, `list[0][1]` is a dictionary. But if it is a dictionary, you can use the `[]` operator to get the key you want `list[0][1]['favorite drink']`.

Comment: Oh ok, i though that the programm would udnerstand it as an extra indexisation for th list and not understand i m aiming at the dictionnary

Comment: The result of the [] operator is whatever you have in the data structure at that position. So, list is a list, list[0] is a tuple, list[1] is a dictionary, and so on. And for each of them you can apply the operations specific to that data type.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are missing ending quote `'` in your sample data.

this is one of the correct way to accomplish your task.

```
beer_counter = 0
for x in list:
    if x[1]['favorite drink'] == 'beer':
        beer_counter += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to fix up your loop a bit and use a `collections.Counter` for easy tally keeping:

```
lst = [("mike", {'age': 27, 'favorite food': 'pizza', 'favorite drink':'beer'}), ("jessie", {'age': 35, 'favorite food': 'eggs','favorite drink':'tea'}), ("frank", {'age': 14, 'favorite food':'bread', 'favorite drink':'fanta'})]
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter()
for x in lst:
    cnt[x[1]['favorite drink']] += 1
```